# How does this star rating work, how does it know how to select all the stars below the one you click on?

Tags: html, css

This is pure HTML and CSS for selecting the stars.

I do get what the js code does but I fail to understand how the stars are selected when I click on a star and al the stars below that one get selected

```css
.rating {
  float: left;
}


/* :not(:checked) is a filter, so that browsers that don’t support :checked don’t 
       follow these rules. Every browser that supports :checked also supports :not(), so
       it doesn’t make the test unnecessarily selective */

.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label {
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0 .1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.rating>input:checked~label {
  color: #f70;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #c60, 2px 2px #940, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: gold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked+label:hover~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: #ea0;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px goldenrod, 2px 2px #B57340, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.rating>label:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}


/* end of Lea's code */


/*
     * Clearfix from html5 boilerplate
     */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}


/*
     * For IE 6/7 only
     * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
     */

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}


/* my stuff */

#status,
button {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
<form id="ratingForm">
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <legend>Please rate:</legend>
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <button class="submit clearfix">Submit</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/zLm4f/6/

Edit: What you see in the below picture is just the mouse moving over those stars. As you move the mouse to the right the all the stars to the left turn yellow/gold so what exactly in CSS does that ? (keeps track of what stars are to the left and selects them. This is not achieved via JS, if you remove the JS code from the Jfillde below the selection mechanism still works
[image]

Comment: note: this is not my code, it is an example I found on Internet

Comment: I dont see JS code in your example!?

Comment: did you click on the JS fiddle link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things going on. I have simplified it with more modern CSS.

1. The items in the fieldset are reversed. This is important because CSS has a selector for elements that come *after* a certain selector but not *before*. The tilde, `~`, is used to select every sibling that comes after an element.
2. The checked radio button `:checked` is used to determine which is the target element, after which all elements should get a certain style applied.

These things combined allow colouring everything after the checked input. Since the list is reversed, it appears to the user as if everything before checked input was coloured. Additionally, the checked input itself is also coloured.

```
.rating>input:checked::before,
.rating>input:checked~input::before
```

In this example, the pseudo-element `before` is used to get the star via `content: '⭐'`. The colouring is done by removing the colour in the default state through a CSS filter: `filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);` and unsetting the filter when the checked, and sibling after checked, condition applies.

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  width: 320px;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.rating>input {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating>input::before {
  content: '⭐';
  filter: grayscale(100%) contrast(200%);
  font-size: 200%;
}

.rating>input:checked::before,
.rating>input:checked~input::before {
  filter: unset;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
  <legend>Please rate:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" title="star5" value="5" />
  <input type="radio" name="rating" title="star4" value="4" />
  <input type="radio" name="rating" title="star3" value="3" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="rating" title="star2" value="2" />
  <input type="radio" name="rating" title="star1" value="1" />
</fieldset>
```

Using these techniques, you could easily expand this with the `hover` state, as in your example.

Another thing that was used in your example is the `+` which is similar to `~` but it only applies to the first silibing instead of all sibling. It appears to be redundant.